# javascript: how to make function run faster

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, time, sequence

so i have to write a function which meets the following requirements:

```
Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

Example:

For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false;

There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.

You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 3].

Input/Output

[time limit] 4000ms (js)
[input] array.integer sequence

Guaranteed constraints:
2 ≤ sequence.length ≤ 105,
-105 ≤ sequence[i] ≤ 105.
```

so my code works except for one problem--there are 30 tests it has to pass with the time constraint of 4000ms, but it always times out on the 30th test, every time. i have tried modifying it so that it runs faster, but each time i do so it no longer works correctly. although i technically only have to write one function, i broke it up into three separate functions. here's my code:

```
var greater = function(a, b) {
  if (a < b) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

function greaterThan(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    var curr = arr[i]
    var next = arr[i + 1]
    if (greater(curr, next) === false) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  for(var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    var newArr = sequence.slice()
    newArr.splice(i, 1)
    if (greaterThan(newArr) === true) {
      return true
    } 
  }
  return false
}
```

so how can i make it run faster without using two for-loops/iterations to do this?

Comment: get rid of `greater()` ... no need for all the function calls when it is only used in one place and is such a simple conditional

Comment: Question is probably a better fit on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, the body of the for loop in *greaterThan* can be `if (arr[i] >= arr[i+1]) return false`.

Comment: There's an O(n) solution you can google. You don't need to loop through them for 2 times. Just try to think if you can come up with a solution that only loops once.

Comment: Both the `slice()` and `splice()` calls are creating new arrays each time through the loop.  I would try to eliminate these by coming up with an algorithm that can do the processing on the original sequence in place.

Comment: Something is fishy The posted code takes a small fraction of a second to check 30 sequences of length 105 on a slow machine. How are you testing it and have you checked that no test case violates the "guaranteed" constraints?

Comment: so even if i remove the 'greater' function and just use a conditional in the 'greaterThan' function, it still times out. the tests are not my own (and i don't have access to them), i'm submitting them on a browser based compiler and IDE

Answer (score 0):

Improving the algorithm may bring better results than improving the code. Here's the problem:

1. If the sequence is not strictly increasing at index `i`, such that  `a[i]>=a[i+1]` is true, either `a[i]` or  `a[i+1]` must be removed to possibly make the array strictly increasing - they can't both be left in place.
2. If the input array is to be fixable by removing only one element, and it decreases after the `i`th element it must become strictly increasing by removing the element with subscript `i` or `(i+1)`.

Compare the efficiency of checking the original array and at most two sub arrays before returning `true` or `false`, with checking the same number of arrays as the original array's length. I'll leave re-writing the code to you - it's not my homework :-)